# co-NP but not NP problems

Tags: p-vs-np, co-np

What are the problems that are in **co-NP** but not in **NP**?

i.e, those problems where incorrect strings can be deterministically verified in polynomial time but the correct strings can't be.

Comment: Do you know the definition of coNP? Are you familiar with NP-complete problems? Can you use this to find a good candidate for such a problem?
Note that we don't actually know whether coNP=NP or not. It is conjectured that $coNP\neq NP$, and it is widely believed to be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**co-NP** is the set of complements of problems that are in **NP**. So **co-NP** contains problems such as non-3-colourability, Boolean unsatisfiability and so on.
Most complexity theorists believe that **NP$\,\neq\,$co-NP** and one consequence of this is that the complement of any **NP**-complete problem would be in **co-NP** but not in **NP**.

Wikipedia has [more information on **co-NP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP).

Answer (score 3):

Your question assumes $NP \neq coNP$, which is currently unknown (but generally assumed to be true). If $NP = coNP$, there is no problem satisfying your requirements.

If $NP \neq coNP$, the complement of any NP-complete problem works. You can find a [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems).